Data Breakpoint when Dictionary key-value is changed
Let's say I have a Dictionary:
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["foo"] = "bar";
dict["abc"] = "def";

Is there a way to set a breakpoint or data breakpoint to monitor the value of "foo"? This would mean that dict["foo"] = "bar2"; should trigger such a breakpoint, but dict["abc"] = "def2"; should not.
I assume it could either be done by using a data breakpoint, or by using a property setter and putting a normal breakpoint there but I'm not sure if it can be done without subclassing Dictionary<string, string>().
Edit:
I feel like the answers below didn't understand quite what my problem is:
I am talking about finding out where the code is that makes the change, in a rather big project that uses the "event-driven" approach rather heavily, so control flow is almost impossible to trace correctly. I need to be able to get a trigger whenever the value is changed, from an unknown line of code. I need the breakpoint in order to find the line of code that tampers with the data in the first place.

Breakpoints are a feature of the IDE, in this case Visual Studio. Not the class. Especially data breakpoints. You can edit the condition of a breakpoint to respond to data changes or you can specify a data breakpoint from the watch window. You can right click on a value in the Watch, Autos, Locals window and select Break when value changes.  There are restrictions though

Rather than subclassing Dictionary<string, string>, could you define a new class called (say) ObservableString with no public constructors but with an implicit conversion defined from string to ObservableString, and use a Dictionary<ObservableString, string>, along with some extra logic to detect a change to the dictionary item's value? This would trigger your implicit conversion whenever a user tried to assign to, say, dict["abc"]. You could access/output the stack trace via Reflection inside the implicit conversion.


Uncheck Enable Just My Code, check Enable Source Link support and Suppress JIT optimization on module load in the debug options.
This will enable you to debug the core source code.

Add a breakpoint at dict["foo"] = "bar";
The purpose of this step is to help you find the source of the indexer setter.

Debug your program and wait for it to break at the point.
Press F11 to step in.
If everything is OK, you will be inside the setter so that you can set a breakpoint with the condition "foo".Equals(key) at that line.

Now you can remove the first breakpoint and debug the program again.



Thank you, but could you see my edit? The location of dict["foo"] = "bar" is obviously unknown to me - if I knew where in the codebase that line of code is, I wouldn't be needing the breakpoint. Obviously my example code is just that - an example to illustrate what I need.

@sashoalm: The purpose of breaking at dict["foo"] = "bar" is just to make it easier to find the indexer setter and set the breakpoint. You could add that line of code yourself anywhere, debug in and set the breakpoint. It will affect all dictionaries though, not just the one you're "watching".
